# Postman Basic Authentication without username and Password

Tags: postman

I am trying to make a POST request using Postman. The credentials that I have is just an API key and not username and password.

Now in Postman as soon as I select "Basic Auth" it prompts for username and password. So I left these fields as blank and went to Headers to give my own Authorization key-value which leaves me with two "Authorization" fields as shown in the screenshot and I get invalid authentication response.

The authorization works fine using CUrl command in CLI. Is there a workaround for this?

[image: Postman screen shot]

Answer (score 6):

Just keep the Authorization setting to 'No Auth' and manually add in your `Authorization` Request Header into the `Headers` tab, like you have done so in the image.

[image]

If you don’t use anything from the Authorization tab, then you won’t see this 'extra' header and the request should work the same as you would if you used cURL.

More about Postman Authorization can be found here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue.
It seems that Postman is using a ":" character to join the username and password fields together before base64 encoding.

A workaround is to use the "API Key" type for authorization:
[image]

You can use a Postman variable to store the value of the api key.